# Suggested edit gained 4 reputation points

Tags: bug, reputation, suggested-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1298740) to a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218239/inherit-from-a-base-class-and-provide-the-inheritance-type-to-overridden-method). This edit got approved, but I received 4 reputation points for that suggestion.

[image]

Shouldn't that be just two points - or am I missing something here?

My first thought was that I suggested two edits, but that would have been to simple:

[image]

Looking at the [revision history of that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14218239/revisions) I can see 4 revisions - could it be that I received credit for the edit made by Nuffin? And if so, is that a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

Comment: Did you suggest multiple edits to that post?

Comment: You had 4 accepts on the edit rather than the required 3. The final 2 edits were submitted in the same second as each other... might indicate some race condition with both the final accepts *accepting* the edit.

Comment: @Servy no, just one - see updated question.

Comment: @Matt thanks for the meta-tag edit - didn't know about that ;) Regarding the race condition: That seems to me like a bug...

Comment: @Spontifixus: Two different Matt's (or Mat's ;)). I'm only guessing at the race condition of course... not a lot of detail to go on :).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I don't think that this is an exact duplicate. Apart from that this question seems to be answered, too - see Matt's comment from Jan 8'13 at 15:52.

Comment: That's not a answer, it's a guess @Spontifixus... (one I upvoted back when it was first made).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of other option, too. That was the case when I had got 4 points for an edit. I had first suggested an edit on some post.

Just after I edited, I noticed something in the same post, which needed to be improved. While I was making necessary changes, my previous edit got approved. I submitted second edit, which was also approved. As per my knowledge, revision graphs don't show different edits for same user which was done during 5 minutes. And that duration was just a minute, or two. So it showed like "4 points for one suggested edit."

Comment: That could have been the case in your case. My question already states that I suggested only _one_ edit.

Comment: @Spontifixus, Ok. I thought you might have done some edit in that 5 minute period, which was also approved after first edit. It doesn't show in graphs. So I just suggested