# Suggested Edit didn't award 2 reputation points

Tags: bug, reputation, suggested-edits

This is not a duplicate question, please read first what occurred.

I just did editing on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15245991/2130528), and it was [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1658561) by four users.
My reputation was 93 before the suggested edit. After approval it showed me my reputation as 95 for a second in the title, but then it was back to 93 again.
When I look in my reputation history, it shows +4 from that editing but still I can't see any reputation increase in my reputation history. I have already ticked the "show removed posts" checkbox.

> [image]

I am confused; what is the result of my editing operation ?

Comment: This seems to be a bug; it seems like *both* of the last two reviewers managed to accept your edit (as only *3* reviewers are needed), which is why you see 2 entries in your reputation history (and a +4 rather than a +2). However, as to *where* this +4/+2 has gone, I have no idea.

Comment: @Matt, can you please edit my question and put this image in it , http://i.stack.imgur.com/qSLh3.jpg  i can't do it as i dont have enough reputation.

Comment: You can visit http://stackoverflow.com/reputation then hit the 'recalc' button at the bottom to iron out any irregularities.

Comment: ... FYI also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161974/suggested-edit-gained-4-reputation-points, it is related.

Comment: @Matt, got it, thanks man

Comment: @Jacob please note that you are always able to edit your own posts

Comment: @WouterJ, i know that part, but that time i was having < 10 reputation so i couldn't able to insert image in my question, that's why i request Matt to do same.

Comment: I got that too!

Comment: @Jacob - Did you suggest edit on that question only one time or twice?