# Four points for editing?

Tags: support, bug, reputation, suggested-edits

Just now I edited an answer and got four points instead of two.

[image]

I checked *[Suggested edit gained 4 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161974/suggested-edit-gained-4-reputation-points)*, but I already had a few other suggested edits approved, and it has always been two points...

Here is the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21154838/revisions

Is this a bug?

**Update:**

Checking the revisions, I can see two revisions, both at same time and the content is also the same. Links are also identical. Possibly this is the cause of the issue I feel:

[image]

Comment: It would help diagnose the issue if you linked the question it occurred in.

Comment: @jmac looks like this is the edited post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21154838/839601

Comment: Thanks gnat.. thats the link..

Comment: You could edit again to do the syntax as well and get another 2 rep

Comment: Maybe, posting the edit data two times (clicking the button twice) and some connection or database issues may cause the *edit validity check* to fail and recorded it twice to db.

Comment: Agree with @FallenAngel, sounds like temporary glitch in database. Unless someone can find a way to reproduce.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Marking it as duplicate obviously suggests this was observed earlier..:)

Comment: @RoyMJ database glitch can happen more than once, yep.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : okay...:)

Answer (score 8):

You suggested two separate edits [as seen on the revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21154838/revisions):

> [image: Two Revisions]

Both seem to lead to the same suggested edit though: [First](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1092078) and [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1092078).

The suggested edit was approved and seems to have given you credit for two edits even though the second seems to have no content. That would be +4 rep.

Comment: Actually i havent submitted it twice.. And if you see, you can understand there are no changes also in both versions?

Comment: I wouldnt be able to submit unchanged version right without sufficient changes?

Comment: You have linked the same suggested edit twice. Also in [the revision page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21154838/revisions) see the timing of both suggested edits.

Comment: @hims056 not quite so, it started with revisions history which lists same suggestion twice: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21154838/revisions (smells like a data race somewhere in the system)

Comment: @hims056 : Actually there are two revisions, both at same time and same content. That ought to be the issue...

Comment: @hims, sorry 'bout that, I copied the two links separately, not realizing they both lead to the same place. That's odd.

Comment: No one can suggest the same post twice.

Comment: @Bala, yet somehow, as shown there, it happened.

Comment: I really should've checked the network tool in browser to see what was happening..